# PostgresQL How to implement pessimistic locking on nullable outer join columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms

I'm trying to implement pessimistic locking on a complex entity with a foreign keys, but Postgres does not support SELECT FOR UPDATE with OUTER JOIN nullable fields. Is there any workaround?

Example:

```
create table A(
  id serial primary key,
  name character varying(20) not null
);

create table B(
  id serial primary key,
  a_id int references a(id) on delete cascade not null,
  name character varying(20) not null
);

create table C(
  id serial primary key,
  b_id int references b(id) on delete cascade not null,
  name character varying(20) not null
);

// Query:
SELECT *
FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
  LEFT JOIN C ON B.id = C.b_id
WHERE A.id = 5;
```

I need a way to perform such query, locking rows from tables a, b and c for update. Also I need to lock inserting rows in table B and C, that reference on a selected rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
  LEFT JOIN C ON B.id = C.b_id
WHERE A.id = 5
FOR UPDATE; <<---- DOES NOT WORK IN POSTGRES
```

Now I see the only way to do this is to make 3 SELECT statements selecting rows from tables A, B and C for update and join them on an application side, but this way seems to be slower than joining on DB side.

Is there any way to perform JOIN in database, locking all selected rows?

Comment: You only need to lock the row in table `A`. If your competing threads lock in the same way there's no need to lock `B` or `C`. This is the typical case when you need to make changes to, for example, an invoice and all its lines; you only need to lock the invoice row, and then you can change the invoice or it children rows, and finally commit.

Comment: I need to lock A and B, because I need to forbid adding rows in B, that reference selected rows in A (locking A works pretty good on that), and adding rows in C that reference selected (not null) rows in B (that's a problem). In this case a workaround can be locking rows in A when trying to add rows in C. Have no better ideas on how to do it :(

Comment: Instead of simple ```INSERT INTO C (b_id, name) values (1, 'c1');``` Make a: ```SELECT * FROM B INNER JOIN A ON B.a_id = A.id WHERE B.id = 1 FOR UPDATE; INSERT INTO C (b_id, name) values (1, 'c1');```

Answer (score -4):

There is no possibility into a query to enforce a pessimistic locking in PostGreSQL because PostGreSQL does not accept any table hint nor no hint at all in any part of the query like Micosoft SQL Server, Oracle database or any other RDBMS (you have to pay for this by acquiring the Enterprise version).

The only thing you can do is to write a SQL script or a PF "function" as a procedure in which you will explicitely locks tables inside an explicit transaction.

Something like :

```
BEGIN WORK;
LOCK TABLE A IN ROW EXCLUSIVE;
LOCK TABLE B IN ROW EXCLUSIVE;
LOCK TABLE C IN ROW EXCLUSIVE;

SELECT *
FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
  LEFT JOIN C ON B.id = C.b_id
WHERE A.id = 5

...

COMMIT WORK;
```

This is not the only thing that PG cannot do, take a look over this paper : "[PostgreSQL vs. SQL Server (MSSQL) – part 3 – Very Extremely Detailed Comparison](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/)"

Comment: Your paper is not up to date in many features of PostgreSQL. Plenty of that stuff you mention is not implemented in PostgreSQL is actually available.

Comment: Typical FUD article, too bad. Writing an article in April 2021, pointing out some CVE's in 2019 for PostgreSQL and then claiming how wonderful SQL Server is because no serieus issues have been found the last 12 months. 2021 minus 12 months = 2020. That makes PostgreSQL also a wonder product! You just "forgot" to write that down... SQL Server is a great product, just like Oracle, DB2 and PostgreSQL. They are all different and all have their pro's and con's. Please don't make yourself look like a fool when writing about ayatollahs, you're better then that.